# Team project is not deleted completely from Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I created a project called `Energy2` in Azure DevOps. Then I deleted it by going to `Organization Settings`, selecting `Projects` tab which is selected by default, the using `...` menu of `Energy2` and choosing `Delete` and then confirming by typing project's name.

However, it encountered an error and I don't remember the error since I closed the window.

Now the problem is that it's gone in the Azure DevOps web portal, but it's not gone from the list of team projects in `Source Control Explorer` of `Team Explorer` window in Visual Studio.

[image]

[image]

Do you know of any other option that I can solve this?

Comment: Which VS version do you use?

Comment: Do you still have it mapped in your workspace? Have you done a get latest?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2017, Community Edition, 15.8.6.

Comment: For developers who want to map the entire collection, it's there. For others who have mapped it already it's there also. Technically, it's not dependent upon being mapped or not.